# Else is being displayed even if correct

Tags: python, python-3.x

I've been having a problem in my multiplication game where else would be displayed even if the answer was correct.

Here is a sample of the code:

```
for num in range(0,1):
    number1 = random.randint(2,5)
    number2 = random.randint(2,5)
    answer = number1*number2
    guess = input("What is %d x %d? " % (number1, number2))

if guess == answer:
    print('Correct')
else:
    print('Incorrect')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In `Python 3.x`, Input returns a `str`, vs. in `Python 2.x` where it attempted to evaluate the input as python code. And `str == int` always returns `False`, and doesn't throw an `exception`. You'd need to change your code to:

```
if guess == str(answer):
```

if you'd like to avoid throwing exceptions if the input isn't actually a number, or

```
gess = int(input(...))
```

if you intend to actually use `guess` as a number later on, but will then have to handle what happens if the user enters not a number.